# https over http - Does it mean downloading more MBs?

Tags: caching, ssl, https

When a page with static image files is downloaded via `https/ssl` protocol, the browser caches them in encrypted form.

When the browser starts next session with the server, the `ssl` encryption key changes and the browser can no longer decrypt the cached resource in its next key. Does it mean for `https`, the static resources will always be downloaded from either the CDN or remote web server. Particulary, for cases when http-headers `expires/cache-control` have been set?

Comment: *"caches them in encrypted form"* - What makes you think that?

Comment: oh yes, the browser can cache the decrypted static asset... now, i see i was a little dumb...

Answer (score 0):

The data in the cache is not encrypted, and can be reused between sessions. See for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/21/internet-explorer-may-bypass-cache-for-cross-domain-https-content.aspx that explicitly says that closing the browser and contacting the same page again will result in cache hits.